# make 3 random elements in the array invisible

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have 5 buttons in an array I want to make random three of these invisible when pressed on button. so the last two buttons will be visible

I tried like this:

```
 @IBAction func eliminateChoiceClicked(_ sender: Any) {

       let buttons:[UIButton] = [buttonA,buttonB,buttonC,buttonD,buttonE]
       let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(3)))
       buttons[randomNumber].isHidden = !buttons[randomNumber].isHidden

    }
```

but it takes first elements [0,1,2] and only 1 button is invisible at each press

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently only selecting one button.  Change that to a loop to select 3.  Remove the selected button from the array and make it invisible. Finally, make the remaining buttons visible:

```
@IBAction func eliminateChoiceClicked(_ sender: Any) {

   var buttons:[UIButton] = [buttonA,buttonB,buttonC,buttonD,buttonE]

   // Select 3 buttons randomly and hide them
   for _ in 1...3 {
       let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(buttons.count)))
       let button = buttons.remove(at: randomNumber)
       button.isHidden = true
   }

   // Make the remaining buttons visible
   for button in buttons {
       button.isHidden = false
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just written a neat extension to get a random elements from an array:

```
extension Array {
    func randomItems(count: Int) -> [Element] {
        guard count <= self.count else { fatalError() }
        var notUsedElements: [Element] = self
        var randomElements: [Element] = []
        while randomElements.count != count {
            randomElements.append(notUsedElements.remove(at: Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(notUsedElements.count)))))
        }
        return randomElements
    }
}
```

Using this you can achieve what you want this way:

```
@IBAction func eliminateChoiceClicked(_ sender: Any) {

    let buttons:[UIButton] = [buttonA, buttonB, buttonC, buttonD, buttonE]
    // make sure all are visible at the beginning
    buttons.forEach { (button) in
        button.isHidden = false
    }

    // hide random 3:
    buttons.randomItems(count: 3).forEach { (button) in
        button.isHidden = true
    }
}
```